# Capacitive touch sensor design

Tags: pcb, button, capacitive

I made a PCB with several capacitive pads to be read by IQS127.

They work, but any material I put close to the PCB surface will trigger the output, even the 8 mm glass I'm going to use.

The pads diameters is 20 mm, no copper below nor aside (just the traces needed for IQS127).

The problem is just too much sensitivity or perhaps there are some other serious mistakes in the design?

EDIT:
Added schematic and layout.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What design?  Please edit your question and add your schematic and PCB layout.

Comment: From what I understand (after a VERY quick look around the datasheet)  it will trigger once when you place something on the pad while it is running, but will then adapt to the new conditions.  So, if you place the glass on it with it turned on, it will trigger then should work properly afterwards.  If the glass is there when you turn it on, then it should work properly from the beginning.

Comment: Have you tried to adjust the Proximity Threshold and Touch Threshold? (Datasheet page 9)

Comment: I solved following after the explanation of JRE, but I'm going to update anyway the question. Any feedback about layout is welcome!

JRE, thank you very much for pointing out that behavior. I didn't understand it. It works that way!

Uwe: unfortunately I haven't the Configuration Tool yet. Anyway the registers are OTP...

Comment: Question updated with schematic and layout.